# jqueryで<td>～</td>の値を取得したい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

下記のようなtableがあります。

```
<table>
    <tr><td>a</td><td><a href="#" onclick="onClick();">link</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>b</td><td><a href="#" onclick="onClick();">link</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>c</td><td><a href="#" onclick="onClick();">link</a></td></tr>
</table>

<script>
    function onClick(){
        // tdの値を取得したい
    }
</script>
```

一番上のリンクがクリックされたらaを、2番目だったらbを取得したいです。
$(this).parents.text()で取得しようとしたら何も取得できませんでした。
どのように取得すればよいのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下はどうでしょうか。

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><td>a</td><td><a href="#" onclick="onClick(this);">link</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>b</td><td><a href="#" onclick="onClick(this);">link</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>c</td><td><a href="#" onclick="onClick(this);">link</a></td></tr>
</table>

<script>
    function onClick(link){
      // 冗長なので、closestを使用する
      // console.log($(link).parent().parent().find('td').first().text());
      console.log($(link).closest('tr').find('td').first().text());
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

何番目のlinkが選択されたか、indexで番号を得る方法のサンプル。

```js
    function onClick(a){
        // tdの値を取得したい
      var no =  $('a').index(a);//何番目かの番号を得る
      var td_string = $('tr').eq(no).find('td').eq(0).html();
      $('#td0').html(td_string);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="td0"></div>
<table>
    <tr><td>a</td><td><a href="#" onclick="onClick(this);">link</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>b</td><td><a href="#" onclick="onClick(this);">link</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>c</td><td><a href="#" onclick="onClick(this);">link</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><td>a</td><td><a href="#" onclick="onClick(this);">link</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>b</td><td><a href="#" onclick="onClick(this);">link</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>c</td><td><a href="#" onclick="onClick(this);">link</a></td></tr>
</table>

<script>
    function onClick(link){
      //親の兄弟要素から直前を選択した方が早いような気がする
      console.log($(link).parent().prev().text());
    }
</script>
```