# テーブルから指定した行の値を取得したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  <table id="tbl1">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>列１</th><th>列２</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <input type="submit" value=" ボタン"/>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

事前にJS側で、let tmp = 2;　と定義したものを使って
B2を取得したい場合JSのコードはどのように描けばよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: [マルチポスト](https://teratail.com/questions/171206)先もあわせてどうぞ。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tr`のchildrenに対して`eq`を呼び出すことで行の値を取得できます。
下記のサンプルコードでは、`id=tbl1`の`tbody`要素から`tr`の2行目の子要素(`td`)の末尾から`text`を取得しています。

```
let tmp = 2;
let text = $("#tbl1").children("tbody").children("tr").eq(tmp - 1).children().last().text();
```

`eq`のインデックスは0から始まるので、"B2"を取得する場合は`eq(1)`を指定する点に注意が必要です。
なおご覧の通りコードが冗長になるので、下記のサンプルコードのように`id`や`name`を`td`に指定して直接参照する方が可読性は高まります。

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      function sampleSubmit() {
          let tmp = $("#sel1").val();
          //let text = $("#tbl1").children("tbody").children("tr").eq(tmp - 1).children().last().text();
          let text = $("#td" + tmp).text();
          $('#sampleOutput')[0].innerText = text;
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <select id="sel1">
      <option value="1"/>A1</option>
      <option value="2"/>B1</option>
      <option value="3"/>C1</option>
    </select>
    <input id="aaa" type="button" value=" ボタン" onClick="sampleSubmit()"/>
  </form>
  <table id="tbl1">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>列１</th><th>列２</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>A1</td><td id="td1">A2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>B1</td><td id="td2">B2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>C1</td><td id="td3">C2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <span id="sampleOutput"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

[SOの類似質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/46943)
[別サイトの類似質問](https://teratail.com/questions/71867)